# what is the code for the default action of the 'back' button in android?

Tags: android

I have an edittext and a save button displayed. When back key is pressed, I want them to be gone (if they are visible) and the next back press will do the default action of the back button.
The code is as follows:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            event.startTracking();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
                && !event.isCanceled()) {
            if(save.isShown())
            {
                 save.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                 text.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);
            }
                    //else ???????????????

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

The above code has following outcomes:
1. when edittext and button is visible, then back button makes them gone but the following press renders nothing. Although if back button is kept pressed, we go back to the previous activity.
2. when edittext and button are initially not there, pressing of back button stops the application unexpectedly.Although if back button is kept pressed, we go back to the previous activity.

In the place of else, I have tried finish() but the program is stopping unexpectedly.
return false also results same..

Comment: Here is the suggestion. Why dont you implement Save & Edit as a dialog box ? I think that fits your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  doStuff();
}
```

[Link Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)

**Edit**

Wait, what about a long press?  If I'm reading the original question correctly you want the initial back press to hide some views, and the second to behave normally?  Why not just something like this:

```
private boolean flag = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(flag) {
    super.onBackPressed();
  } else {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    flag = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: with this method, i cant even go back to the previous activity on the long press of the back button.... there has to be something written after else...

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled()) {
    if(save.isShown()) {
```

by

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled() && save.isShown()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    myMethod();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

It's very important to call the supermethod when you override methods like this.  Put any code you want to execute before the supermethod call and you should be golden!

EDIT:

before the supercall, not after.

Comment: thanks this was somewhat useful.. i used the following code:
    @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  
  if(save.isShown())
  {save.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
     tagValueTB.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);}
  else super.onBackPressed();
 }

but still  when edittext and button are initially not there, pressing of back button stops the application unexpectedly

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help.  As a new user, make sure to upvote correct answers and if you asked them (as in this case), make sure to mark the answer as correct.  This way, other users can find the correct answer quicker if they are asking the same question.